# ejs - "Unexpected identifier" when using include in for loop

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm using `<% include components/aside.ejs %>` or `<% include components/head.ejs %>` somewhere in my code without any problem. But when I use `include` in a for loop like this

```
<%
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    include components/head.ejs;
}
%>
```

, I get `Unexpected identifier in [file path] while compiling ejs`.

Is there any obvious mistake that I'm not noticing?

Answer (score 15):

To fix a breaking change, as of EJS 3.x, the syntax for an include has gone from `<%- include components/head.ejs %>` to `<%- include('components/head.ejs'); %>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
    <% for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){ %>
     <%- include('component/footer') %>
    <% }; %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the template tags `<%` and `%>` on every line, like this:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){ %>
    <%- include components/head.ejs %>
<% }; %>
```

Comment: This goes from "Unexpected identifier" to "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" when trying this answer.  #TrashFire