# How can I include partial views in a ejs file?

Tags: ejs, partial-views

I am trying to include a simple partial template in my ejs file. I watched several tutorials explaining how to do that and I see no difference between their code and mine. I also checked the path a few times, but I'm always getting the same error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\views\preview.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:626:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:366:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:215:18)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Leandro.DESKTOP-C1AK72S\Documents\Visual Studio Code GitHub\Server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
```

This is the code snippet:

```
     <% include partials/timerWidget.ejs %>
```

Removing this line of code, the error is gone

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609132/1041722
There is a different tag: `<%-`

Comment: No, this didn´t work as well

Comment: this then https://stackoverflow.com/a/59325661/1041722

Comment: Oh, yes. That helped a lot. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ejs - "Unexpected identifier" when using include in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429895/ejs-unexpected-identifier-when-using-include-in-for-loop)